# How do I get the ascii value of "Next Line" / "Enter" from the user

Tags: java

I need to get the ASCII value of each character entered. I have char and whitespace but can not seem to get a value for "next line" / enter.

I thought to use an if statement saying that if(letter == '\n')
(ascii = 10) but it 1. does not work and 2. it is forcing the value manually and I am trying to figure out how to get it read and assigned automatically.

```
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        char letter = scan.nextLine().charAt(0);

        int ascii = (int) letter;

        System.out.println(ascii);

        scan.close();
```

Comment: You don't. `Scanner.nextLine()` *removes* the line terminator, as does `BufferedReader.readLine()`. You will never see it.

Comment: Why did you delete your `WorkItem` question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56640516/for-some-reason-calling-dowork-on-the-worker-is-resulting-in-the-second-word-rep

Answer (score 1):

The **scanner eats the end-of-line** after detecting it. You get the characters input up to, but including, the end-of-line.

Also, you should not use `char` to track single letters. As a simple 16-bit value, it can only represent characters from the Basic Plane of Unicode, less than half the 137,000 characters defined in Unicode.

Use the integer-based methods such as [`String::codePointAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#codePointAt(int)) and `String::codePoints`.

Answer (score -2):

The ASCII value of the new character is 10 (0x0A). The value of carriage return is 13 (0x0D).

```
public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String hello = "Hello World!\n";
    System.out.print(hello);

    int letter = (int)hello.charAt(hello.length()-1);
    System.out.println(letter);
  }
}
```

Comment: What the other guy posted and what I posted is closer to what I am looking for. However, when asking the user to input a character and if they just press enter (new line) it still does not display a value though. Why is that?

Comment: @James, see the comment that user207421 added to your original post. This is the reason why I showed this example. You can't get the new line character from that method, because it is consumed before you can get a hold of it. Also, if you downvoted my answer, consider that your problem statement reads: "I need to get the ASCII value of each character entered." and I was able to demonstrate that. Therefore, it is not appropriate to downvote.

Comment: I did not downvote anything. I was just asking the question for I am trying to understand. Sorry you were downvoted, but since my rank is lower I cannot upvote or downvote responses.